# Soft body simulation going through mesh object with collision modifier on

Tags: collision, soft-body

[image]I have an .obj that has a mesh cache and collisions modifier on it. however when I press play my soft body necklace falls right through the object. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated
Link to the blender file and mdd files below
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15zVGzKDF9vYtXjW0BgxaFgv7iYlixS-H?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15zVGzKDF9vYtXjW0BgxaFgv7iYlixS-H?usp=sharing

Comment: pls add blend file, thx

Comment: I only see a BLEND file and an MTL file, no MDD. But even without it I can see in the modifier stack, the _MeshCache_ comes after the _Collision_ modifier. If the softbody should take the modified mesh into account, the _Collision_ modifier needs to be below the _MeshCache_. More I can't tell without the MDD file.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The mdd file was taking a few minutes to upload if you check the link the file is in there now. Also i originally had the collision modifier below the mesh cache however i changed it because it caused blender to move at 1 mph. But even with the mesh cache 1st the necklace stills falls through.

Comment: @Chris files added

Comment: ok i ran a test where i went into edit mode with .obj selected. Pressed p to separate and make a copy, then ran a simulation and it worked as should for the copy of the .obj. without the mesh cache modifier applied to it. However before i removed the mesh cache modifier from the copy of the .obj the necklace was going through the .obj.  is the mesh cache file somehow cancelling out the softbody simulation? if so why and is there a solution for it?

Comment: 3.3 GB? You're serious? Oh dear... Well, anyway - I'm not sure about _MeshCache_ and _Soft Body_ simulations at the moment, but at least I know for example that _Cloth_ simulations do not work with characters deformed by armatures - because the cloth only gets affected by the original mesh, not the mesh that was modified by posing through an armature.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann is 3 gbs too big? Sorry bout that. Is there a way to "bake" the mesh cache modifier to the .obj?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Found a solution bro
Instead using the .mdd file I imported my animation via fbx. The chain reacts to fbx.
Just one question. My chain with the soft body simulation is parented to the fbx to match animation movement of my character. However if I want to use my .obj instead of .fbx can i bake the simulation and then delete the .fbx or will that mess up the parenting? Should I just make the fbx invisibl